# Graylog correlation rules original messages

Tags: graylog

I’m using Graylog V3.1.2 with an enterprise plugin.

I created a correlation rule that triggers alert whenever two events occur.

When I’m looking at the “All events” stream and find the correlation event in the origin_context property I’m getting only the last event that triggered this rule.

I have the same problem with aggregation rules that I’m not getting the origin_context for them.

Is there a way to see all original events that triggered the correlation rule or aggregation rules?

Thank you.